# Как посчитать количество строк по условиям с группировкой

Tags: mysql, запрос, select, выборка

Доброго времени суток, подскажите пожалуйста по вот какому вопросу:

Есть таблица вида:

```
+-----------------------+
|id|user_id|point|status|
-------------------------
|1 |  1    |  3  |   0  |
-------------------------
|2 |  1    |  3  |   0  |
-------------------------
|3 |  2    |  1  |   0  |
-------------------------
|4 |  2    |  0  |   0  |
-------------------------
|5 |  3    |  3  |   0  |
-------------------------
|6 |  3    |  1  |   0  |
-------------------------
|7 |  1    |  0  |   1  |
+-----------------------+
```

Каков должен быть SQL запрос чтобы получить таблицу вида:

```
+-----------------------------------+
|user_id|total_point|point_3|point_1|
-------------------------------------
|  1    |  6        |  2    |   0   |
-------------------------------------
|  3    |  4        |  1    |   1   |
-------------------------------------
|  2    |  1        |  0    |   1   |
+-----------------------------------+
```

Чтобы были выбраны строки где status = 0 и выборка была сгруппирована по user_id, также для каждого  user_id посчитаны:

1. общее количество очков (total_point)
2. количество очков = 3 (point_3)
3. количество очков = 1 (point_1)

И упорядочены они сначала по point_1, затем point_3 и total_point.

Comment: А что вы сами пытались сделать. до какого уже запроса дошли

Comment: Что-то похожее, но оно не работает:

`SELECT user_id, SUM(point) AS total_point, 
COUNT(point) AS point_3 GROUP BY point HAVING point = 3,
COUNT(point) AS point_1 GROUP BY point HAVING point = 1
FROM `table`
WHERE status = 0
GROUP BY user_id
ORDER BY point_1,point_3,total_point`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы в запросе все перепутали, group by пишется один раз и после where, за ним пишется having и так же только один на запрос. И having вам ничем не поможет потому как позволяет только убрать некоторые собранные группы из выдачи. Думаю вам стоило бы задать вопрос на подобии "как посчитать количество по условию", остальное то вы боле менее представляете.

```
SELECT user_id, SUM(point) AS total_point, SUM(point=3) point_3, SUM(point=1) point_1
  FROM table
 WHERE status = 0
 GROUP BY user_id
 ORDER BY point_1,point_3,total_point
```

Приведенный синтаксис исключительно для MySQL, в других СУБД пришлось бы использовать `sum(case point when 3 then 1 else 0 end)`. В MySQL же оператор сравнения `point=3` возвращает 1 если условие выполнилось и 0 если нет. sum просто суммирует полученные единицы.

Comment: Благодарю за исчерпывающий ответ, ваш ответ мне очень помог!