# Как подсчитать в запросе MySQL количество вхождений подстроки по каждому полю

Tags: mysql

Задача: выводить кол-во совпадений в подсказках поиска.

Исходная таблица MySQL:

```
+----+-----------+---------------+-------------------+---------------+
| id |   name    |   district    |      street       |     metro     |
+----+-----------+---------------+-------------------+---------------+
|  1 | Виват     | Петроградский | пр-кт Левашовский | Чкаловская    |
|  2 | Петроград | Московский    | 4-й Предпортовый  | Звёздная      |
|  3 | Ура       | Петроградский | наб Аптекарская   | Петроградская |
+----+-----------+---------------+-------------------+---------------+
```

Использую запрос типа:

```
SELECT name, district, street, metro
    FROM table WHERE (name LIKE '%петроград%' OR district LIKE '%петроград%' OR street LIKE '%петроград%' OR metro LIKE '%петроград%'
```

Выводить в подсказках хочу:

```
Петроград (название) - 1 совпадение
Петроградский (район) - 2 совпадения
Петроградская (метро) - 1 совпадение
```

Пока додумался метить поля в запросе таким образом:

```
SELECT name, district, street, metro, CONCAT_WS(',',case when `name` LIKE '%петроград%' then 'name' end,
          case when `district` LIKE '%петроград%' then 'district' end,
          case when `street` LIKE '%петроград%' then 'street' end,
          case when `metro` LIKE '%петроград%' then 'metro' end) fields
        FROM table WHERE (name LIKE '%петроград%' OR district LIKE '%петроград%' OR street LIKE '%петроград%' OR metro LIKE '%петроград%'
```

Чтобы на выходе получилось

```
+-----------+---------------+-------------------+---------------+----------------+
|   name    |   district    |      street       |     metro     |     field      |
+-----------+---------------+-------------------+---------------+----------------+
| Виват     | Петроградский | пр-кт Левашовский | Чкаловская    | district       |
| Петроград | Московский    | 4-й Предпортовый  | Звёздная      | name           |
| Ура       | Петроградский | наб Аптекарская   | Петроградская | district,metro |
+-----------+---------------+-------------------+---------------+----------------+
```

дальше уже в php посчитать кол-во совпадающих полей из field и вывести в подсказках.
Чувствую, что построил 5-этажный деревянный самолет.
Можно ли упростить задачу и подсчитать вхождения сразу в sql запросе?

*Уточнение: в результате запроса нужны все данные из таблицы, не только кол-во совпадений по полям.*

Comment: Можно налепить запрос и подсчитать сразу.
С помощью подзапросов и агрегатной функции count(), я думаю.

Comment: У вас удобный запрос, 'петроград', а что, если поискать по 'ская', у вас найдутся вхождения в разных названиях, вам это надо учитывать, или нет? Если надо, тогда придётся делать группировку по именованиям, и тогда возможно проще выполнить три запроса, на district, street и metro, хотя их можно и объединить через union all

Comment: select concat(district, ' (район)') as title, count(*) as count from table where district like '%?%' group by district union all далее аналогично для улиц и метро

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/582338/194569  только в вашем случае нет колонки по которой группировать, так как надо получить одну итоговую строку, так что из вышеприведенного ответа уберите group by и все остальные поля. Но не ясно зачем вы пытались выводить совпадения через запятую отдельным полем, может вам кроме количеств нужны еще индивидуальные записи ?

Comment: @Mike спасибо, посмотрел пример. Там используются арифметические операции, в исходных данных числовые значения. Не могу понять, как это на строки перенести.

Comment: Уточнил задачу: в результате запроса нужны все данные из таблицы, не только кол-во совпадений по полям.

Comment: @PrimusSingularis да, Вы правы. Нужно искать начиная с 2-х символов. Если искать 'ск', получится вывод: district - 3 совпадения, street - 2, metro - 2.

Comment: @EdWard Вы действительно хотите и количества и исходные данные в одном запросе ? Будет отдельная строка с итогами, вам надо будет уже на клиенте отличить ее от строк с обычными данными. при желании можно сортировкой сделать ее первой или последней, что бы проще было. А что касается условий внутри sum() то никакой разницы нет числовые там поля или символьные. любая логическая операция в MySQL, включая like возвращают 0 или 1, которые и считает sum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select id, max(name) name, max(district) district, max(street) street, max(metro) metro,
       sum(name LIKE '%петроград%') name_l,
       sum(district like '%петроград%') district_l,
       sum(street like '%петроград%') street_l,
       sum(metro like '%петроград%') metro_l
  from Table1
  WHERE concat(name,district,metro,street) LIKE '%петроград%'
  GROUP BY id WITH ROLLUP
```

Выбирает все подходящие исходные данные, при этом в колонках district_l, street_l и metro_l стоит 1 если условие совпало, иначе 0. Группировка по id (фактически никакой группировки нет, так как id уникален), позволяет добавить к запросу предложение `WITH ROLLUP`, которое добавляет к результатам строку с итогами. В этой строке id=NULL (что позволяет отличить ее от записей с данными), а поля `*_l` при этом содержат суммы по всей выборке, т.е. искомые количества совпадений.

Пример на [sqlfiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b233ef/2)

Comment: Благодарю, получается то, что нужно с ROLLUP!