# Как сгруппировать строки в MySQL по условию

Tags: mysql

Есть таблица в MYSQL вида

```
id id_user
1  1
2  1
3  2
4  3
5  3
6  1
7  4
8  1
```

Как можно посчитать количество строк id_user, в плане

```
1 - 4 строки
2 - 1 строка
3 - 2 строки
4 - 1 строка
```

Сейчас я вижу выход только сначала запросить все id_user, которые есть, а затем вторым запросом просто посчитать отдельно циклом

```
SELECT COUNT(id_user) FROM table WHERE id_user='1'
```

А можно ли как то одним запросом сразу вывести информацию по всем id_user?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как посчитать количество строк по условиям с группировкой](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/582330/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%be-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d1%83%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%8f%d0%bc-%d1%81-%d0%b3%d1%80%d1%83%d0%bf%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b9)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте группировку:

```
SELECT id_user, COUNT(*) cnt
FROM tbl
GROUP BY id_user;
```

UPD: начальный вариант был неверный

Comment: @NowhereMan Вы не правы, посмотрите пример на офф сайте https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html группировка по году означает что на каждый год будет показана сумма, а тут группировка по Id означает что на каждый id будет показано  число пользователей. А по id_user выполняется функция count

Comment: @NowhereMan и даже в том вопросе на который вы сослались - user_id по нему группировка - значит он выводится по одному разу, а по остальным полям подсчет.

Comment: посмотрите [пример](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a1fb54/3) -- вы что-то очень сильно путаете

Comment: @NowhereMan мы оба неправы, третий вариант верный ))) , спасибо за такой удобный инструмент!

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a1fb54/8

Comment: И что верного в третьем варианте?  Какой в нём смысл?  Странно, что этот запрос выполнился, так как агрегация была выполнена по неправильному полю

Comment: @NowhereMan Да. люто плюсую вы полностью правы., спасибо огромное!

Answer (score 2):

**Правильный ответ** -- группировка должна выполняться по полю `id_user`.
Также стоит отсортировать по соответствующему полю.

```sql
SELECT id_user, COUNT(*) cnt
FROM tbl
GROUP BY id_user
ORDER BY id_user
```

[Онлайн демо](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a1fb54/3)

```
id_user cnt
1       4
2       1
3       2
4       1
```